# Windows store app -- get font metrics?

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-store-apps, fontmetrics

In a Windows store app, how can I programmatically get [font metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) of the Segoe UI font?  (baseline, ascent, and so forth)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting Ch. Petzold from his book about Windows Store Apps:

> To do something like this in a generalized way, you’d need access to font metrics, 
>   which are available to a Windows 8 application only through DirectX. I’ll show you how to do that in 
>   Chapter 15, "Going Native."

**EDIT**
[The book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145369079.do)
[Source codes](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735671768-files/9780735671768_files.zip) -> check example in CSharp\Chapter15\LookAtFontMetrics

Comment: is this still the case in Windows 10?